# Python PULP Unsupported Operand Type(s) TypeError

Tags: python, optimization, pulp

I am trying to set up some specific constraint in PULP and feel like I am missing something simple.  All of the issues are all the same TypeError, showing UNSUPPORTED OPERAND between 'generator' and int or continuous.

I have tried various solutions, the code that I have is provided, although does not work.

```
YPER = 365
HE = 24

yearlyhours = [(i,j) for i in range(YPER) for j in range(HE)]

YAHL = pulp.LpVariable.dicts('YAHL', yearlyhours, lowBound=0, cat='Continuous')
YALL = pulp.LpVariable.dicts('YALL', yearlyhours, lowBound=0, cat='Continuous')
YAHLINT = pulp.LpVariable.dicts('YAHLINT', yearlyhours, lowBound=0, cat='Integer')
YAHLBIN = pulp.LpVariable.dicts('YAHLBIN', yearlyhours, lowBound=0, cat='Binary')

model += pulp.lpSum([YAHLINT[(i,j)] for i in range(YPER) for j in range(HE) if j >= 7 and j <= 22]) == (YAHL[i][j] for i in range(YPER) for j in range(HE) if j >= 7 and j <= 22) / 25

model += pulp.lpSum([YAHL[(i,j)] for i in range(YPER) for j in range(HE) if j >= 7 and j <= 22]) >= 0 * (YAHLBIN[i][j] for i in range(YPER) for j in range(HE) if j >= 7 and j <= 22)
```

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'generator' and 'int'

and

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'int' and 'generator'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a [generator expression](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/) here:

```
(YAHL[i][j] for i in range(YPER) for j in range(HE) if j >= 7 and j <= 22)
```

I guess it's not what you really want.

You should change according to your goal

e.g.,

```
== pulp.lpsum([YAHL[i][j] for i in range(YPER) for j in range(HE) if j >= 7 and j <= 22])
```